# Как сказать грамотно про духи?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

Духи могут быть вкусными? Или так нельзя говорить?

Answer (score 1):

Вкусные духи? Мне думается, что очень даже можно так сказать.

В словаре Ефремовой:
[вкусный](https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), прил.
**1.** Приятный на вкус | Вызывающий представление о приятной, аппетитной пище.
**2.** *перен. разг.* Доставляющий удовольствие; нравящийся.

*— М-м-м, какие **вкусные духи**, – протянул он так, что у меня мурашки по коже забегали* (Марина Орлова. Всего одна смерть, чтобы обрести счастье).

*— Милый мой человек, мы часто сами не ведаем, что творим.

Ее голос немного успокаивал. От нее пахло **вкусными духами** и добротой.*
Светлана Исаенко. Монстры, с которыми мы живем

Comment: Тогда можно было бы говорить "вкусный аэрозоль", "вкусный дезодорант" и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнение** (с примерами)

Не поленилась — "поползала" по Нацкорпусу:

*Ты!.. И не воображай, что я тебя люблю... А так, побаловаться... **Бабы** всегда **вкусные** и... нахальные...* (В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река);
*Так вот, есть у этого самого Курта такие очень **вкусные штуки** ― не то шванки, не то фабльо, пес их знает, как они по науке называются: бытовые **сценки**, в стихах, с двумя-тремя действующими лицами...* (Юлий Даниэль. Письма из заключения);
*Закурили после ужина **вкусные** болгарские **сигареты**, слушали по транзистору далекую музыку...* (Сергей Штейнберг. Ореол Зурбагана);
*Другие исчезли в казарме или бросились брататься с разомлевшим сытым дневальным да расхватывать **вкусные** его **сигареты*** (Олег Павлов. Дело Матюшина);
*― Только не плачь, ― предупреждаю я, ― а то вся наша работа пойдет насмарку. У тебя очень **вкусные сигареты**. Можно еще?* (Владимир Войнович. Замысел);
*Такие по-журналистски **вкусные**, интересные **статьи** стали редкостью, а жаль!* («Известия», 27.09.2002);
*Рядом с этим нахальным, слегка нарциссическим трепом нередко попадаются **мысли** блестящие, очень точные и **вкусные*** (Клариса Пульсон. Книги);
*Что меня больше привлекает: запах женского тела или **вкусные духи**?* (Игорь Сахновский. Заговор ангелов)

Конечно же, никто не жует сигареты, не поедает женщин, не пьет духи, не пшикает в рот или нос аэрозолем (парфюм, кстати, бывает и в аэрозольной упаковке). Речь ведь идет о переносном значении, разговорном употреблении.
У Ожегова: вкусный — выражающий аппетит (но ведь аппетит — это не только ощущение голода или желание есть), удовольствие, ощущение приятного.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ли сказать, что духи вкусные? Если вы их пьете и делитесь впечатлениями - то да, можно.
Во всех остальных случаях вкусным может быть только их аромат.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что люди воспримут такое предложение, как предложение с фигуральным приёмом. А там уже вам решать, по вкусу ли вам такой приём. Но ничего безграмотного тут нет, потому что метафора может быть сколь угодно изощрённой.